# MySQL Update Inner Join tables query

Tags: mysql, compiler-errors

I have no idea what the problem is. Using MySQL 5.0 I get a compile error when attempting to run the following MySQL update query:

```
UPDATE  b
SET b.mapx = g.latitude,
    b.mapy = g.longitude
FROM business AS b
INNER JOIN business_geocode g ON b.business_id = g.business_id
WHERE (b.mapx = '' OR b.mapx = 0) AND
      g.latitude > 0
```

All the field names are correct. Any thoughts?

Comment: i even removed the alias, when I change it to a SELECT b.* FROM business b inner join  it works

Comment: This syntax seems to be of SQL Server.
For mysql you need put the joins after "update [table name]".

Answer (score 511, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE business AS b
INNER JOIN business_geocode AS g ON b.business_id = g.business_id
SET b.mapx = g.latitude,
  b.mapy = g.longitude
WHERE  (b.mapx = '' or b.mapx = 0) and
  g.latitude > 0
```

### Update:

Since you said the query yielded a syntax error, I created some tables that I could test it against and confirmed that there is no syntax error in my query:

```
mysql> create table business (business_id int unsigned primary key auto_increment, mapx varchar(255), mapy varchar(255)) engine=innodb;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> create table business_geocode (business_geocode_id int unsigned primary key auto_increment, business_id int unsigned not null, latitude varchar(255) not null, longitude varchar(255) not null, foreign key (business_id) references business(business_id)) engine=innodb;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> UPDATE business AS b
    -> INNER JOIN business_geocode AS g ON b.business_id = g.business_id
    -> SET b.mapx = g.latitude,
    ->   b.mapy = g.longitude
    -> WHERE  (b.mapx = '' or b.mapx = 0) and
    ->   g.latitude > 0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

See? No syntax error. I tested against MySQL 5.5.8.

Comment: I tried that and am getting the same error.

--
Error on getting execution plan:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE business as b
INNER JOIN business_geocode g ON b.business_id = g.busines' at line 1

Comment: Please post the results of `show create table business;` and `show create table business_geocode;` so I can test my query a little better. Thanks.

Comment: There is no syntax error. I just confirmed it and updated my answer.

Comment: @user719316: There's something fishy *before* that query...are you missing a semicolon?

Comment: @Bobby: You're probably right about that. That would explain why the OP is getting a syntax error when it runs fine on my computer.

Comment: @Joakim The `AS` keyword is optional. But since you mentioned it, I added it to the answer for the sake of consistency, since I did use it on the first alias in the same query.

Answer (score 22):

The `SET` clause should come **after** the table specification.

```
UPDATE business AS b
INNER JOIN business_geocode g ON b.business_id = g.business_id
SET b.mapx = g.latitude,
  b.mapy = g.longitude
WHERE  (b.mapx = '' or b.mapx = 0) and
  g.latitude > 0
```

Answer (score -3):

For MySql WorkBench, Please use below :

```
update emp as a
inner join department b on a.department_id=b.id
set a.department_name=b.name
where a.emp_id in (10,11,12);
```