# SQL UPDATE with INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I'm trying to use this query

```
UPDATE products  
SET products.product_price = '87.00000'
FROM products
INNER JOIN product_category
ON products.product_id = product_category.product_id 
WHERE product_category.category_id = '64'
```

However I receive this error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM table products INNER JOIN table product_category ON prod' at line 3`

I don't see any syntax error. I have made this query from examples on this forum.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057565/mysql-update-statement-inner-join-tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the `FROM products` line.
and put the
`SET ...` line just before the `WHERE` clause.

to be clear :

```
UPDATE ...
JOIN ...
SET ...
WHERE ...
```

you could also do

```
UPDATE products p
SET p.product_price='87.00000'
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL 
              FROM product_category pc
              WHERE p.product_id = pc.product_id
              AND pc.category_id = '64');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
UPDATE products 
INNER JOIN product_category
  ON products.product_id = product_category.product_id 
SET products.product_price = '87.00000'
WHERE product_category.category_id = '64';
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00fee)

Answer (score 1):

I think the SET clause needs to be after the table references and before the WHERE clause, like this:

```
UPDATE products
 INNER
  JOIN product_category
    ON products.product_id = product_category.product_id 
   SET products.product_price = '87.00000'
 WHERE product_category.category_id = '64'
```

---

Here's how I get that syntax when I need an UPDATE like that. I always start with a select statement, and that lets me know which rows are going to be updated. For example:

```
SELECT p.*, c.*
  FROM products p
  JOIN product_category c
    ON p.product_id = c.product_id 
 WHERE c.category_id = '64'
```

To convert that to an update statement, I add a "`SET`" clause after the table references and before the `WHERE` clause, and then replace "`SELECT ... FROM`" with the "`UPDATE`" keyword. Voila.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE products
INNER JOIN product_category
ON products.product_id = product_category.product_id 
SET products.product_price = '87.00000'
WHERE product_category.category_id = '64'
```