# Update sql table using inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

i'm trying to update my sql table using inner join.
I have 2 tables:
`users` and `warnings`

So i want to update my `users` table and set value **'yes'** to filed `users.awarn`
where `users.id_level = '3'` and inner join table `warnings` using id and check if `warnings.active = 'yes'`

bellow is my command:

```
UPDATE users
SET    users.awarn = 'yes'
INNER JOIN warnings
ON users.id = warnings.userid
WHERE users.id_level = '3'
AND warnings.active = 'yes'
```

but phpmyadmin return syntax error.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057565/mysql-update-statement-inner-join-tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your order of operation is wrong SET has to come after JOIN so:

```
UPDATE users
INNER JOIN warnings
        ON users.id = warnings.userid
SET  users.awarn = 'yes'
WHERE users.id_level = '3'
AND warnings.active = 'yes'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct syntax for MySQL:

```
UPDATE users INNER JOIN
       warnings
       ON users.id = warnings.userid
    SET users.awarn = 'yes'
    WHERE users.id_level = '3' AND warnings.active = 'yes';
```