# How do I use INNER JOIN in an UPDATE statement?

Tags: php, mysql, xhtml

I have 2 mysql tables that are joined, in the database, by the descriptionId field.

```
dataTable.dataId
dataTable.descriptionId
dataTable.userId
dataTable.value

descriptionLookupTable.descriptionId
descriptionLookupTable.descriptionName
```

In PHP, I am trying to update the field: dataTable.value, when `dataTable.descriptionID = Gender` and the `dataTable.userId = $_SESSION['userId']`.

For example in the descriptionLookupTable: `descriptionLookupTable.descriptionId = 1` and `descriptionLookupTable.descriptionName = Gender`.  And in the dataTable: `dataTable.descriptionID = 1`.

I understand the part that deals with the userID by using:

```
"WHERE dataTable.userId = '" . $_SESSION['userId'] . "'";
```

But I can't figure out how to use INNER JOIN.

The following query does not work.

```
$query = "UPDATE dataTable
  INNER JOIN descriptionLookupTable
  ON dataTable.descriptionId = descriptionLookupTable.descriptionId
  AND descriptionLookupTable.descriptionName = Gender
  SET Gender = '$gender' WHERE dataTable.user_id = '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'";
```

The error message is: `Unknown column 'Gender' in 'field list'`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057565/mysql-update-statement-inner-join-tables

Comment: Try this `SET dataTable.Gender='...'`

Comment: Thanks but when I try it I get Error msg: Unknown column 'dataTable.Gender' in 'field list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gender apparently is not a column in your table. One of the field must be named Gender for you to be able to update its content

what about trying to update a field which is in your table :) :

```
SET dataTable.value = '$gender' WHERE dataTable.user_id = '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'";
```

Comment: Thanks but when I try it I get Error msg: Unknown column 'dataTable.value' in 'field list'.

Comment: hmmm. how come mysql would recognize dataTable.descriptionId for the join but not dataTable.value. are you sure about capitalization and the name of your fields? could you post the structure of your tables? like the output of phpmyadmin when you export the structure only to the screen

Comment: oh and be sure to put gender between colons 'gender' as VolkerK said. this is effectively a problem which you will run into after you rule out the problem of column names

Comment: Thank you to everyone!  The combination of ideas from Felix and Volkerk worked!  The following mysql statement worked: $query = "UPDATE dataTable INNER JOIN descriptionLookupTable ON dataTable.descriptionId = descriptionLookupTable.descriptionId AND descriptionLookupTable.descriptionName = 'Gender' SET dataTable.value = '$gender' WHERE dataTable.user_id = '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'";

Comment: Actually there is a typo in my last comment wrt user_id.  The following is the fix: $query = "UPDATE dataTable INNER JOIN descriptionLookupTable ON dataTable.descriptionId = descriptionLookupTable.descriptionId AND descriptionLookupTable.descriptionName = 'Gender' SET dataTable.value = '$gender' WHERE dataTable.userId = '" . $_SESSION['userId'] . "'";

Answer (score 0):

```
descriptionLookupTable.descriptionName = Gender
```

`Gender` in this case is a string literal, therefore you have to mark it as such

```
descriptionLookupTable.descriptionName = 'Gender'
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but I get the same answer.  Thanks though.

Comment: no idea why that would be voted down. you need those colons for sql to work, even though this is not the first problem that will appear from the query