# Update query to use joined table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this query :

```
 $sql ="SELECT * FROM card c JOIN driver d ON c.referred_as=d.referred_as WHERE d.ID='$id'";
```

It needs to be updated to include the 3rd table which is a joined table containing the driver and card id's from their respective tables.

Table 1 is called `card` . The fields that are important are:

`state_id` - This table has 3 values (1,2,3)
   `associated_driver` - called `referred_as` on `driver` table // Not actually part of the table . Created by the 3rd table
    `referred_as` - called `associated_card` on `driver` table
Table 2 is called `driver`.

The fields that are important are:
`ID` - The auto incremented value of the table
`associated_card` - Has a value , normally some number e.g 123555 
// Not actually part of the table .

Created by the 3rd table
`referred_as` - The name of the driver () called `associated_driver` on card table

Forgot to add this table :

Table 3 is called `card_driver`. The fields that are important are:

`driver_id` - The id from the driver table that links to the card
`card_id` - The id from the card table that links to the driver

What I want to happen :

When a user enters their id from the `driver` table, it will compare a field that both tables have i.e the `associated_card` field (called `referred_as` on the card table).

The `associated_card` is from the joined table which I don't know how to get into the query.

Any help is welcomed. If you need me to explain it more , I will.

```
--
-- Table structure for table `card`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `card` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `startdate` date NOT NULL,
  `enddate` date NOT NULL,
  `state_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `referred_as` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;


--
-- Table structure for table `card_driver`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `card_driver` (
  `card_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `driver_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


--
-- Table structure for table `driver`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `driver` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `title` varchar(40) default NULL,
  `supplier_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `referred_as` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=12 ;
```

Some images :

[image: This is the driver table]
[image: This is the card table]

Comment: It will be easy to understand if you share your table schemas as well

Comment: do you mean the stuff from the sql file?

Comment: see if this question helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057565/mysql-update-statement-inner-join-tables

Comment: I dont really understand mysql. I just have to use it for this project

Comment: I really hope `$id` is [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) because it doesn't look like it is.

Comment: Yes the $id is escaped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `card_driver` table seems to implement a many-to-many relationship between rows in your `card` table and your `driver` table. Tables like this are usually called *join tables*.

Join tables like this show the relationship between two so-called *detail tables*, in this case `card` and `driver`.

I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean when you describe your `referred_as` columns in your two detail tables.

I think you're asking for all the `card` items that are related to a particular `driver`. You can get that sort of result like this:

```
SELECT card.id, card. startdate, card.enddate, card.state_id, card.referred_as,
       driver.id AS driverid, driver.title, driver.supplier_id, 
       driver.referred_as
  FROM driver
  LEFT JOIN card_driver ON card.id = card_driver.driver_id
  LEFT JOIN card        ON card_driver.card_id = card.id
 WHERE driver.id = '$id'
```

This will give you one row per card assigned to that driver via the many-to-many relationship in the `card_driver` table. Each row will contain information about the driver and the card.

As you can see it works by joining the join table, and then joining the other detail table.

Pro tip: Don't use `SELECT *` in production software; you are much better off choosing the columns you need returned from the query explicitly.

Comment: I will add some screenshots of the card and drive tables so you can get a better understanding of the referred as column . Also the querys dosent work . error - #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'driver'

Comment: oops, sorry for the typo in my query.