# Update table from joining multiple tables in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Hi I would like to update my table but its giving me an error.

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
```

This is my script

```
UPDATE table1 
SET last_name = table3.lastname, 
first_name = table3.firstname,
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table2.entity_id = table1.entity_id
INNER JOIN table3
ON table3.biometric_id = table2.biometric_id;
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057565/mysql-update-statement-inner-join-tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work given you're using `MySql` -- `UPDATE... JOIN... SET...`:

```
UPDATE table1 t1 
    JOIN table2 t2
        ON t2.entity_id = t1.entity_id
    JOIN table3 t3
        ON t3.biometric_id = t2.biometric_id;
SET t1.last_name = t3.lastname,
    t1.first_name = t3.firstname
```