# UPDATE query SUM multiple selects

Tags: mysql

I need to update a field calculated by the sum of multiple selects. The selection part is working, but I can't find a way to update the user table

```
user

+------+---------+
| id   | total   |
+------+---------+
| 1    |         | 
| 2    |         |

unita

+------+-------+-----+
| id   | uid   | num |
+------+-------+-----+
| 1    | 1     | 25  |
| 1    | 2     | 10  |

unitb

+------+-------+-----+
| id   | uid   | num |
+------+-------+-----+
| 9    | 1     | 225 |
| 9    | 2     | 10  |

class 

+------+--------+------+
| id   | name   | cost |
+------+--------+------+
| 1    | class1 | 100  |
| 9    | class9 | 500  |

SELECT uid, SUM(score) FROM (
    SELECT unita.uid, SUM(class.cost * unita.num) AS cost FROM unita, class WHERE unita.id = class.id GROUP BY unita.uid
    UNION
    SELECT unita.uid, SUM(class.cost * unitb.num) AS cost FROM unitb, class WHERE unitb.id = class.id GROUP BY unitb.uid
) x GROUP BY uid
```

The update command should sum all cost per user

```
User 1: (25*100)+(225*500) = 115000
User 2: (10*100)+(10*500) = 6000
```

It this possible within 1 SQL command. The unit tables are locked, so I can't modify anything

Comment: Just add `update user u join ( your select query till group by uid )y on y.uid = u.uid set u.total = y.score` also give alias for the select part as `SELECT uid, SUM(score) as score ...`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057565/mysql-update-statement-inner-join-tables

Comment: See this link below [link][1] 

hope it help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `join` to bring in the results from your subquery:

```
UPDATE user u JOIN
       (SELECT uid, SUM(score) as total
        FROM (SELECT unita.uid, SUM(class.cost * unita.num) AS cost
              FROM unita JOIN
                   class 
                   ON unita.id = class.id
              GROUP BY unita.uid
              UNION ALL
              SELECT unita.uid, SUM(class.cost * unitb.num) AS cost
              FROM unitb JOIN
                   class 
                   ON unitb.id = class.id
              GROUP BY unitb.uid
             ) x
        GROUP BY uid
       ) newvals
       ON u.id = newvals.uid
    SET u.total = newvals.total;
```

Three notes:

1. Note the use of `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`.  Not only does this improve performance because duplicates are not eliminated, but it also fixes a potential problem if both subqueries return the same value.
2. Note the use of proper `join` syntax.  Simple rule:  never use commas in the `from` clause.
3. This will not set the total to 0 if there is no match.  If you desire this, change the `join` to a `left join` and the `set` to  `SET u.total = COALESCE(newvals.total, 0)`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I never knew this was possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the update-join syntax:

```
UPDATE `user` u
JOIN   (SELECT   uid, SUM(score) AS total
        FROM     (SELECT unita.uid, SUM(class.cost * unita.num) AS cost 
                  FROM     unita, class 
                  WHERE    unita.id = class.id 
                  GROUP BY unita.uid
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT   unitb.uid, SUM(class.cost * unitb.num) AS cost
                  FROM     unitb, class 
                  WHERE    unitb.id = class.id
                  GROUP BY unitb.uid) x 
        GROUP BY uid) s ON s.uid = u.id
SET    u.total = s.total
```

**Notes:**

1. The inner query in the OP has a bug. Since it uses `union` instead of `union all`, if the same `uid` has the same total score in both units, it will only be counted once, instead of twice. The above query fixes this.
2. Implicit joins have been deprecated for ages. The above query still uses them to math the OP's style, but the use of explicit joins is highly recommended.

E.g.:

```
UPDATE `user` u
JOIN   (SELECT   uid, SUM(score) AS total
        FROM     (SELECT unita.uid, SUM(class.cost * unita.num) AS cost 
                  FROM     unita
                  JOIN     class ON unita.id = class.id 
                  GROUP BY unita.uid
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT   unitb.uid, SUM(class.cost * unitb.num) AS cost
                  FROM     unitb
                  JOIN     class ON unitb.id = class.id
                  GROUP BY unitb.uid) x 
        GROUP BY uid) s ON s.uid = u.id
SET    u.total = s.total
```

Comment: Are all those little GROUP BYs more efficient than one big one?

Comment: Hi Mureinik, thanks for your help. I marked Gordons answer as solution. His answer was a little more complete.