# mysql update one table with select sum() from another

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have the following query, which works:

```
select filename, hour, sum(joe) as joe_total, sum(bob) as bob_total
from t1
group by filename, hour
```

This gives thousands of rows of data under the following columns:

```
filename, hour, joe_total, bob_total
```

Each filename contains 24 hours, so the first row of results would be

```
filename1, 1, [joe_total_value_hour1], [bob_total_value_hour1]
```

... and the second row would be

```
filename1, 2, [joe_total_value_hour2], [bob_total_value_hour2]
```

... etc.

I have another table called t2 with the following fields:

```
filename, hour, joe_total, bob_total, mary_total, gertrude_total
```

The table t2 also has thousands of rows (more than the result of the select above), but currently the columns joe_total and bob_total contain only zeros and need to be updated.

So I want to update t2 so that

```
t2.joe_total = [resuls from the select].joe_total
```

and similarly for t2.bob_total for each filename/hour.

Any ideas how I could accomplish this?

Comment: Danish, no not so far. I had hoped I could just do this from the query window in phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so here's the query that worked:

```
update t2 t2u
inner join
(SELECT filename, HOUR , SUM( joe) ) AS joe_total, SUM( bob ) AS bob_total FROM t1 GROUP BY filename, HOUR) t
on (t2u.filename =t.filename and t2u.hour = t.hour)
SET      t2u.joe_total = t.joe_total,
    t2u.bob_total = t.bob_total,
    ...
```

Many thanks to Jon C for helping to break my mental icejam.

Comment: You're right, my query works on SQL Server and probably other DBMS but not on MySQL. I noticed that your query has an unnecessary closing parenthesis "SUM( joe) )". Glad you worked it out

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
UPDATE t2 SET 
    t2.joe_total = t.joe_total,
    t2.bob_total = t.bob_total,
    ...
    FROM  
    (  
        select filename, hour, sum(joe) as joe_total, sum(bob) as bob_total
        from t1
        group by filename, hour 
    ) t  
WHERE t2.filename = t.filename
AND t2.hour = t.hour
```

Comment: looks like that's zeroing in on a solution, thanks. However, not sure I'm reading it right -- I don't understand what the "FROM" does.

Comment: You need the "FROM" to include the query on t1 and treat the results as a new table t and then join that table t with the target table t2.

Comment: thanks again. I keep getting a syntax error near 'from (select ... '. Can't understand why, but found this stack thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057565/mysql-update-statement-inner-join-tables), which points to a solution that involves an inner join. It worked on a single filename/hour combo, so maybe that's the way to go