# UPDATE Query Giving me an SQL Error (1064)

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I am trying to update a table in my database from another table.  Here is my Syntax, but I can't seem to find any issues with it. I keep getting SQL Error (1064).

```
UPDATE customers b
SET customers.takerid = customer_update_2016.ot
FROM customer_update_2016 a, customers b
WHERE a.phone = b.phone && a.lname = b.lname
```

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM customer_update_2016 a, customers b WHERE a.phone = b.phone & a.lname =b' at line 3

Solution:

```
UPDATE customers
INNER JOIN customer_update_2016
ON customers.phone = customer_update_2016.phone
AND customers.lname = customer_update_2016.lname 
SET customers.takerid = customer_update_2016.ot
```

Comment: I think you're missing a `JOIN` to use multiple tables in the query like this. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982919/sql-update-query-using-joins

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MYSQL Update Statement Inner Join Tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057565/mysql-update-statement-inner-join-tables)

Comment: So does this really worked? I mean the part that says Solution? or was that the solution you tried to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

you have both mysql and sql-server
which one?

```
UPDATE customers
   SET customers.takerid = customer_update_2016.ot 
  FROM customers
  JOIN customer_update_2016
         on customers.phone =    customer_update_2016.phone 
        and customers.lname =    customer_update_2016.lname 
        and customers.takerid <> customer_update_2016.ot
```

Comment: When I run this query I get: SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to you MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' FROM customers JOIN customer_update_2016 on customers.phone = cu' at line 3

Comment: Pretty sure this works with sql-server.  You had it tagged both ways.

Answer (score 0):

Follow something like this always

```
UPDATE [table1_name] AS t1 
INNER JOIN [table2_name] AS t2 
ON t1.[column1_name] = t2.[column1_name] 
SET t1.[column2_name] = t2.[column2_name];
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem you should use JOIN, in my case I had to pass data from one table to another like you and this was the way that solved my problem, hope it help with yours and others.(I'm using MariaDB v10.4)

```
UPDATE 
table1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS tb2
ON tb2.fieldThatJoin = table1.fieldThatJoin//this part indicate the field that join them
SET 
table1.field1 = tb2.field1;
//if you want to update more than one field then do this
table1.field1 = tb2.field1,
table1.field2 = tb2.field2,
table1.field3 = tb2.field3;//remember to put the ';' at the end
```