# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax... near FROM

Tags: mysql

I'm quite new MySQL but have had some success until hitting this roadblock. Any help would be much appreciated.

I am attempting to update Table 1 based on a matching column in Table 2. MySQL version is 5.5. Here's the 2 tables (apologies for the similar table/column names, should have planned the column naming beforehand):

**Table 1 - domains**

```
+--------+------------------------------------------+----------------+-----------+
| ID     | DomainKeyword                            | GoogleSearches | GoogleCPC |
+--------+------------------------------------------+----------------+-----------+
| 406499 | 1k commandments                          |           NULL |      NULL |
| 406500 | 1k feet deep                             |           NULL |      NULL |
| 406501 | 1 market square                          |           NULL |      NULL |
| 406502 | 1marketst 3012                           |           NULL |      NULL |
| 406503 | 1 massive cashflow                       |           NULL |      NULL |
| 406504 | 1 min tv                                 |           NULL |      NULL |
| 406505 | 1 minutes tv                             |           NULL |      NULL |
| 406506 | 1 minutes tv                             |           NULL |      NULL |
| 406507 | 1 money mentor                           |           NULL |      NULL |
| 406508 | 1 my bia2 music                          |           NULL |      NULL |
| 406509 | 1n4j8                                    |           NULL |      NULL |
```

**Table 2 - googlesearches**

```
+------+----------------------------------+----------+-------+
| ID   | Keyword                          | Searches | CPC   |
+------+----------------------------------+----------+-------+
| 3330 | audio buss                       |      480 |  0.00 |
| 3331 | balls to poverty                 |       30 |  0.00 |
| 3332 | boa homes                        |       10 |  0.00 |
| 3333 | bath construction                |       10 |  0.00 |
| 3334 | bread crumbs catering            |       10 |  0.00 |
| 3335 | complete recruit                 |       90 |  0.00 |
| 3336 | all about carpets                |       10 |  0.00 |
| 3337 | consulting world                 |       10 |  0.00 |
| 3338 | car insurance loans              |       50 |  3.64 |
| 3339 | building experts                 |       50 |  0.00 |
| 3340 | boyfriend jealousy               |       30 |  0.00 |
| 3341 | avid farm shop                   |       30 |  0.00 |
| 3342 | chic bridesmaid                  |       10 |  0.00 |
| 3343 | ad wholesale                     |       10 |  0.00 |
| 3344 | buy game card                    |       10 |  0.00 |
| 3345 | daily driving                    |       10 |  0.00 |
| 3346 | church farm cottage              |      260 |  1.18 |
```

Here is the command, it seems certain commands I run with a 'FROM' throw the same error:

```
UPDATE dest
  SET GoogleSearches = src.Searches,
    GoogleCPC = src.CPC
FROM domains AS dest
INNER JOIN googlesearches AS src
ON dest.DomainKeyword = src.Keyword;
```

The error I am getting when attempting to run the command:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM domains AS dest INNER JOIN googlesearches AS src ON dest.DomainKeyword = ' at line 4
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, a MySQL `UPDATE` query with multiple tables would look as follows: `UPDATE domains, googlesearches SET GoogleSearches = src.Searches, GoogleCPC = src.CPC WHERE domains.DomainKeyword = googlesearches.Keyword;`. I'll move this to an answer should it work.

Comment: update with a join pattern has the `SET` coming at the end

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Inner Join in Update statement In MYSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057565/how-to-use-inner-join-in-update-statement-in-mysql)

Comment: Try this query UPDATE domains dos, googlesearches gs SET dos.GoogleSearches = gs.Searches WHERE dos.DomainKeyword = gs.Keyword;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:
reverse your query...I think it's reversed in mysql than in sql server:

```
UPDATE domains AS dest
INNER JOIN googlesearches AS src ON dest.DomainKeyword = src.Keyword
  SET dest.GoogleSearches = src.Searches,
   dest.GoogleCPC = src.CPC;
```

Comment: Perfect, first ever post on stackoverflow solved in 2 minutes! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
UPDATE domains dos, googlesearches gs SET dos.GoogleSearches = gs.Searches WHERE dos.DomainKeyword = gs.Keyword;
```