# MySQL Update statement with INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql

I have no idea what the problem is. Any thoughts?
I tried to update my first_q column from gradings table.

```
UPDATE gradings g set g.first_q = 90 FROM gradings
INNER JOIN subjects ss
on ss.subject_id = g.subject_id
INNER JOIN students s
ON s.id = g.student_id
INNER JOIN school_years sy
on sy.id = g.sy_id
INNER JOIN teachers t
on t.id = g.teacher_id
WHERE s.id = 1;
```

Comment: Do you get any error or what is your Problem?

Comment: Could you up vote my answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax is wrong. Maybe you should try something like this:

```
UPDATE gradings g 
INNER JOIN subjects ss ON ss.subject_id = g.subject_id
INNER JOIN students s ON s.id = g.student_id
INNER JOIN school_years sy ON sy.id = g.sy_id
INNER JOIN teachers t ON t.id = g.teacher_id
set g.first_q = 90
WHERE s.id = 1;
```

[MySQL Update Inner Join tables query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057565/mysql-update-statement-inner-join-tables)

Comment: Thank you! My syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just remove the `FROM gradings` and put the `JOIN`s before the `SET`