# Mysql update query with join

Tags: mysql

I have two tables **table_A** & **table_B** fields are

**Table_A**

```
id      Name     Code      phone
----------------------------------
 1      ABC       101
 2      BCA       102
 3      ABC       101
```

**Table_B**

```
id       Phone       code
---------------------------
 1        987        101
 2        548        102
 3        887        103
```

I need to update `phone` field in **Table_A**  by taking the value from **Table_B**. I can do this with `php loop` but this table have huge data. more time needed for this.   is there any simple query to update this?

Comment: Are you using  framework or any ORM libraries that use foreign references?

Comment: Is there any simple query to update this?: Yes.   Lots of examples: here's 1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057565/mysql-update-statement-inner-join-tables

Comment: and a [demo](http://rextester.com/QVKK33556) using your data/tables:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use an update with join

```
  update table_A
  inner join table_b on a.code = b.code 
  set a.phone = b.phone
```

Answer (score 2):

This query will do the trick. 
Make sure to create a index on column code on both tables for maximal update speed.

```
UPDATE 
 Table_A
INNER JOIN 
 Table_B
ON
 Table_A.code = Table_B.code 
SET 
 Table_A.phone = Table_B.phone
```