# SQL syntax error INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I'm trying to run this sql query and keeps getting this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID WHERE
>   wp_posts.post_typ' at line 3 (Line 4)

My sql query is this:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET meta_value = "1316"
INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID
WHERE wp_posts.post_type="imagen_dia" AND wp_postmeta.meta_key="ae_post_template"
```

Any help please?

Comment: Missing FROM...

Comment: Which DBMS? Oracle? MySQL? SQL Server? ... The syntax for joined updates differs a lot in the various DBMS. Double quotes are for names by the way; use single quotes for strings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MYSQL Update Statement Inner Join Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057565/mysql-update-statement-inner-join-tables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mysql   the JOIN should be before the set

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID
SET meta_value = "1316"
WHERE wp_posts.post_type="imagen_dia" AND wp_postmeta.meta_key="ae_post_template"
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT!!! Now it works perfectly!! I was using sql all the time not knowing I have to use mysql. You saved my day. Thanks again my friend!! :)

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for joined updates is vendor-specific. So do this without a join to have the update statement simple, readable and safe :-)

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta 
SET meta_value = '1316'
WHERE meta_key = 'ae_post_template'
AND post_id IN (SELECT id FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'imagen_dia');
```

This statement is standard SQL and should work in about every RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `FROM` word:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET meta_value = "1316"
FROM wp_postmeta
INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID
WHERE wp_posts.post_type="imagen_dia" AND wp_postmeta.meta_key="ae_post_template"
```