# SQL - Update after table select and join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

I have two tables.

One table is as follows:
Table1:

| id | title | view | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 117 | title1 | 10 | 21-12-10 |
| 120 | title2 | 21 | 21-12-09 |
| 125 | title3 | 40 | 21-12-08 |
| 127 | title4 | 50 | 21-12-07 |
| ... | ... | ... |  |

The other tables is as follows:
Table2:

| id | view |
| --- | --- |
| 117 | 1158 |
| 120 | 3257 |
| ... | ... |

Table 1 and Table 2 are joined based on id,

and Table 1 is to be updated.

However, since the size of table 1 is very large, I would like to table 1 select based on the date column.

Finally, I want to join the following two tables and update them.

| id | title | view | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 117 | title1 | 10 | 21-12-10 |
| 120 | title2 | 21 | 21-12-09 |

| id | view |
| --- | --- |
| 117 | 1158 |
| 120 | 3257 |
| ... | ... |

After the update table1:

| id | title | view | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 117 | title1 | 1158 | 21-12-10 |
| 120 | title2 | 3257 | 21-12-09 |
| 125 | title3 | 40 | 21-12-08 |
| 127 | title4 | 50 | 21-12-07 |
| ... | ... | ... |  |

Is there a way?

Comment: Can you clarify how you are trying to update Table1? Is it that you only want to update rows in Table1 where the `date` column meets a certain condition (such as equal to, less than, etc.).

Comment: edit my question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL - UPDATE table after SELECT statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70301019/sql-update-table-after-select-statement)

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.View = T2.View
FROM Table1 T1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.Id = T2.Id
--You can include the where condition in this case Date
```

Comment: I'm using mysql and it doesn't work FROM.

Comment: This link should help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057565/mysql-update-inner-join-tables-query