# UPDATE with INNER JOIN phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, update-inner-join

```
UPDATE icmsc100 SET codigo='test'
FROM icmsc100
INNER JOIN icms307
ON icms307.ajusteDeCodigo = icmsc100.codigoItem;
```

I'm trying to use it this way, but it's returning an error, how should it be done?

Error #1064 - Syntax Error

Comment: phpmyadmin is the web interface for (AFAIK) MySQL databases. The error tells that your sql command neither fits MySQL nor the standard SQL notation. Search a bit here in Stackoverflow or Google and you will find the answer with e. g. `mysql update join other table`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Update Inner Join tables query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057565/mysql-update-inner-join-tables-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the data with the Inner Join In MYSQL as below.

```
UPDATE icmsc100 
INNER JOIN icms307 
ON icms307.ajusteDeCodigo = icmsc100.codigoItem
SET codigo='test';
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).